# Facebook API : get page feed with image, text and date

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently able to get a FB page feed using this type of request (using PHP):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{$id}/feed?{$authentication}&limit={$maximum}
```

It gives me last posts from a FB page, with message and publication date. I just want to retrieve this content + each post image (if there is at least one).

So I did this request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{$feed}/feed?{$authentication}&fields=attachments&limit={$maximum}
```

Which retrieves content (text) + pictures. But no date in there...

**What's the best way to retrieve page feed with content text, images and publication date ?**

Comment: Simply add the date field you want to the `fields` parameter …

Comment: Including the `created_time` field should fetch you the date/timestamp of the post itself, e.g. `feed?fields=attachments,created_time` - is that all you're lacking?

Comment: This was I was missing... I didn't know I could put all I want in fields (I ended up with fields=attachments,created_time,message). I looked for that in FB API docs, couldn't find it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: _“I looked for that in FB API docs, couldn't find it.”_ – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the `created_time` field to fetch post timestamps in addition to their textual content (`message`) and any `attachments`:

Example generic request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/(api_version)/(page_id)?fields=feed{created_time,attachments,message}&access_token=(token_id)
```

Example timestamp in the output:

```
"created_time": "2016-03-17T11:33:59+0000"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try these fields:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{$feed}/feed?{$authentication}&fields=created_time,from,link,message,picture,type,attachments,source&limit={$maximum}
```